# How to spin widget form one to another angle over Y-axis in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I want to spin widget from 270 degreee(intially) to 360 degreee. I  tried AnimationController with AnimatedBuilder with Transform, but not able to understand how to build and what lowerbound and uppperbound parameter do.
Here is [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOfNI.jpg)

Inside initState

```
    _controller = AnimationController(
      value: 50,
        animationBehavior: AnimationBehavior.normal,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
        vsync: this)
      ..addListener(() {
        print(rotate.value.toString());
        setState(() {});
      });
    rotate = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 90).animate(_controller);
```

Animated Builder is

```
AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: rotate,
        builder: (context, child) {
          return Transform(
            origin: Offset(100,100),
            child: getChild(context, percent),
            transform: Matrix4.identity()..rotateY(rotate.value/100),
          );
        },
      )
```

It always rotate 360 degree n number of times. I am not able to understand how it working?

Comment: Please add a video clip of what you want to achieve

Comment: Sorry for late reply, i  have shared sample in  the post